# Quasar ScrollArea reset position

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have the following scroll are and with a click event i want that the scroll position gets resettet to 0. However i dont know why the following code is not working. Its exact the same as in the [Quasar Documentation.](https://quasar-framework.org/components/scrolling-utils.html) I also habe the mentioned imports.

```
<q-scroll-area id="test" style="width: 97%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">

methods: {
    handleScroll () {
      const ele = document.getElementById('test') //
      const target = getScrollTarget(ele)
      setScrollPosition(target, 0, 1000);
    },
}
```

Comment: did you used `<q-scroll-observable @scroll="scrollHandler" />` inside `q-scroll-area`?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim yes

Comment: you're scrolling to the same area

Comment: and how can i scroll to top?

Comment: i can give you a simple js code without using that component when you click your element you scroll to the top

Comment: that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can uses the Vue method`.setScrollPosition`

> setScrollPosition(offset[, duration]) Set scroll position to an offset. If a duration (in milliseconds) is specified then the scroll is animated.

Add a `ref` to your q-scroll-area and then in your method, use it an set the scroll position to jump to. For this example, I made the list items clickable, and thus would reset to top position.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data: function () {
    return {
      version: Quasar.version,
      count: 100
    }
  },
  methods: {
   notify: function () {
      this.$q.notify('scroll to top')
    },
    scrollToTop: function () {
      this.notify()
      this.$refs.scrollArea.setScrollPosition(0)
    }
 },
  computed: {
    values () {
      let value = []
      for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
        value.push('This is a placeholder')
      }
      return value
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="q-app">
  <q-scroll-area id="test" style="width: 97%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" ref="scrollArea">
    <q-list>
      <q-item v-for="(val, index) in values" @click.native="scrollToTop">
     {{index}} - {{val}}
      </q-item>
    
    <q-scroll-area>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/stevebor1/pen/MZPWzQ)